# How to add edges/borders to the links in geom_link2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Is there a way to add an edge/border (not sure of the proper word) to the links created using `ggforce::geom_link2` in R? Something similar to points with pch >20.

The issue that I see is that geom_link2 uses `col` instead of `fill` in order to define the colour of the link. Therefore I am not sure how the colour of the border could be defined. In turn that makes me think that there is no way to make a border on the link.
Any idea?
Thanks.

**EDIT 10/02/21:** follow up of the solution from @tjebo.

Here is a reproducible example of the path-crossing issue. The border disappears at the crossing. With 2 paths it is still ok to visualise, but in a complex ordination it gets very messy.

```r
library(ggforce)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- data.frame( x = c(5, 10, 5, 10), y = c(5, 10, 10, 5), width = c(1, 10, 6, 2), colour = letters[1:4], group = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y,  group = group), size = 10, lineend = 'round') +
  geom_link2(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour, group = group), 
             size = 5, lineend = 'round', n = 500)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: sven, Ideally ask this as a new question please ! it was just be conincidenxe that I saw your update because I had this still open in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheeky workaround: Create two geom_link2 plots overlaid. If you want a simple unicolor border, you can as well (and better) use geom_path instead.

Adapted from the example in `?geom_link`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)
lines <- data.frame( x = c(5, 12, 15, 9, 6), y = c(17, 20, 4, 15, 5), xend = c(19, 17, 2, 9, 5), yend = c(10, 18, 7, 12, 1), width = c(1, 10, 6, 2, 3), colour = letters[1:5])

ggplot(lines) +
  geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y,  group = 1), size = 10, lineend = 'round') +
  geom_link2(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour, group = 1), 
             size = 5, lineend = 'round', n = 500)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It looked good, but then I realised that this does not work well if some paths are overlapping/crossing. Then the black border disappears. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: @SvenLEMOINEBAUER it may really help to have a reproducible example where this happens... if you figured out how to reproduce this, then please ask a follow up question, and kindly remember linking to your first question